# How do I look at the IL for my code?

Tags: .net

I have some C# .NET code and out of curiousity I'd like to look at the IL generated for it.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: A quick google search would have produced the answer of `ildasm`. I would downvote, but I don't have enough reputation...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [`ILDASM.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) utility that's built into the .NET framework. For example in a Visual Studio Command prompt you could type the following:

```
ildasm /output:foo.il foo.dll
```

and then enjoy the beauty of the IL contained in your assembly.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the steps to use `ILDASM.exe` tool in `VS 2010`

[Have a look](http://www.ginktage.com/2011/04/display-il-code-in-visual-studio-2010/)